# How to exclude rows with dates that are not in ascending order

Tags: python, pandas

I have a .xlxs file which can be accessed from [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Bc6SwZ3NEGI_WWoEfv_VpUNrKANS-q6e?usp=share_link). This file is only a small idea of what I have, as I have a much larger file which I need to process.

The column dates are a bit messy, there are some typos whereby in column 'Dates' there are a number having the year 2018 whilst due to typos 2017 in row 6 was written instead. The same can be said for row 12 and 13, where the years are 2010 but they should be 2019. I would like to check, that the dates are in ascending order according to the year, if **not** those dates along with the corresponding row should be dropped out. So basically I would like to omit the rows that do not appear to be in ascending order according to the year.

I have included a [snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/air6e.png) of what I want to end up with on python.

**ADDENDUM**

The following is the code to print out the data following some cleaning of dates. `ts[0]` is the file containing the data in 'dates.xlsx' (the one on google drive)

```
date_output_ts = pd.to_datetime(ts[0], dayfirst=True, errors='coerce').dropna()

print(date_output_ts)
```

Then I simply convert to an array:

```
x_array = np.asarray(date_output_ts)
```

and I obtain the following [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msIhU.png).

Then I plotted `x_array` and obtained this [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2j2G.png). The y-axis are the years. The dips you are seeing are the 9 individual errors I am trying to remove.

Comment: Could you post your attempt at solving the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html):

```
diff = df['Date'].diff()
out = df.loc[pd.Series(np.select([diff.lt('0'), diff.ge('365days')],
                                 [False, True], np.nan),
                       index=df.index).ffill().ne(0)]
```

Output:

```
         Date  Mean  N Mean  N SD
0  2018-05-16  89.0    94.0  22.5
1  2018-05-17  92.0    94.9  22.5
2  2018-05-18  93.7    94.6  22.6
3  2018-05-19  93.0    94.6  22.3
5  2018-05-21  95.0    95.0  22.6
6  2018-05-22  91.0    94.0  22.3
7  2019-05-25  88.0    94.3  22.5
8  2019-05-26  93.8    94.6  22.5
9  2019-05-27  88.0    94.3  22.5
12 2019-05-26  93.8    94.6  22.5
13 2019-05-27  88.0    94.3  22.5
14 2020-05-26  93.8    94.6  22.5
15 2020-05-27  88.0    94.3  22.5
16 2020-05-28  93.8    94.6  22.5
17 2020-05-29  88.0    94.3  22.5
18 2020-05-30  93.8    94.6  22.5
```

intermediates:

```
         Date  Mean  N Mean  N SD       diff  indexer
0  2018-05-16  89.0    94.0  22.5        NaT     True
1  2018-05-17  92.0    94.9  22.5     1 days     True
2  2018-05-18  93.7    94.6  22.6     1 days     True
3  2018-05-19  93.0    94.6  22.3     1 days     True
4  2017-05-20  94.0    94.6  22.6  -364 days    False
5  2018-05-21  95.0    95.0  22.6   366 days     True
6  2018-05-22  91.0    94.0  22.3     1 days     True
7  2019-05-25  88.0    94.3  22.5   368 days     True
8  2019-05-26  93.8    94.6  22.5     1 days     True
9  2019-05-27  88.0    94.3  22.5     1 days     True
10 2010-05-22  91.0    94.0  22.3 -3292 days    False
11 2010-05-25  88.0    94.3  22.5     3 days    False
12 2019-05-26  93.8    94.6  22.5  3288 days     True
13 2019-05-27  88.0    94.3  22.5     1 days     True
14 2020-05-26  93.8    94.6  22.5   365 days     True
15 2020-05-27  88.0    94.3  22.5     1 days     True
16 2020-05-28  93.8    94.6  22.5     1 days     True
17 2020-05-29  88.0    94.3  22.5     1 days     True
18 2020-05-30  93.8    94.6  22.5     1 days     True
```

##### alternative

You can also try to get the [`cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummax.html) of the dates, and if is goes backwards, ignore the dates until your above the previous max:

```
out = df.loc[df[0].ge(df[0].cummax())]
```

Visual output:

[image]

Same, but only filtering based on years:

```
out = df.loc[df[0].dt.year.ge(df[0].dt.year.cummax())]
```

Visual output:

[image]

The first orange peak is not an anomaly if you only consider years:

```
308 2019-09-30    3 days
309 2019-10-31   31 days
310 2019-02-10 -263 days  # this is the same year
311 2019-04-10   59 days
312 2019-10-07  180 days
313 2019-10-08    1 days
```

Comment: I tried to follow a similar approach but could not manage. I tried to use your snippet however I got an error. `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'datetime.datetime'`. Not sure how to go about it. I am attaching the entire file with dates [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Bc6SwZ3NEGI_WWoEfv_VpUNrKANS-q6e?usp=share_link) . I will update the post should I manage to fix the issue but till now I'm a bit stuck.

Comment: out of @Justin your second file doesn't load the data as datetime automatically, you must do it manually: `df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0])`, then this works fine (keeps 395 rows out of 1045)

Comment: I plotted the dates that I have from the file provided and there were 9 incorrect instances where the dates were not in ascending order. So basically the code is deducting way too much data if it keeps 395 rows. I would expect to remain with 1036 rows.

Comment: Can you provide some examples? Or your code to plot the graph? Have you understood my logic? you might need some fine-tuning

Comment: @Justin for example in row 292, you jump from `2019-09-29` to `2019-08-30`, is this an anomaly?

Comment: I added another approach

Comment: I added an addendum with some code and figure I mentioned. I only need to fix the jump there is in years. Not months or days. Such as having many rows with the same year for instance 2018, then one of them is 2000, and the rest follow as 2018. I want to remove the year that is 2000.

Comment: Then the last approach should be what you want, see updated details

Comment: Thank you for your help. Sorry to bother you again. I wanted to find the index of the rows I omitted. I tried to use the following `out_index = date_output_ts.index[date_output_ts.dt.year.ge(date_output_ts.dt.year.cummax())].tolist()` however it is not giving me the index. `date_output_ts` is your `df`. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Looks ok, but you should use `lt`, not `ge` to get the dropped indices.